# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.CMS_User'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Error

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'dbo.CMS_User' that match the referencing column list in the foreign
>   key 'FK_CMS_UserSettings_User

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserSettingsUserGUID_CMS_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserSettingsUserGUID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CMS_User] ([UserGUID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserSettingsUserGUID_CMS_User]
GO
```

I am getting the above error while i execute statements

Could you please help me how to create a contraint here, what going wrong while i create it?

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings](
        [UserSettingsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [UserNickName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [UserPicture] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [UserSignature] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UserURLReferrer] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
        [UserCampaign] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [UserMessagingNotificationEmail] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [UserCustomData] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UserRegistrationInfo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UserPreferences] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UserActivationDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
        [UserActivatedByUserID] [int] NULL,
        [UserTimeZoneID] [int] NULL,
        [UserAvatarID] [int] NULL,
        [UserBadgeID] [int] NULL,
        [UserActivityPoints] [int] NULL,
        [UserForumPosts] [int] NULL,
        [UserBlogComments] [int] NULL,
        [UserGender] [int] NULL,
        [UserDateOfBirth] [datetime2](7) NULL,
        [UserMessageBoardPosts] [int] NULL,
        [UserSettingsUserGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_UserSettings_UserSettingsUserGUID]  DEFAULT ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
        [UserSettingsUserID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_UserSettings_UserSettingsUserID]  DEFAULT ((0)),
        [WindowsLiveID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [UserBlogPosts] [int] NULL,
        [UserWaitingForApproval] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_UserSettings_UserWaitingForApproval]  DEFAULT ((0)),
        [UserDialogsConfiguration] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UserDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UserUsedWebParts] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
        [UserUsedWidgets] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
        [UserFacebookID] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [UserAuthenticationGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
        [UserSkype] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [UserIM] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [UserPhone] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
        [UserPosition] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [UserLinkedInID] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [UserLogActivities] [bit] NULL,
        [UserPasswordRequestHash] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [UserInvalidLogOnAttempts] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_UserSettings_UserInvalidLogOnAttempts]  DEFAULT ((0)),
        [UserInvalidLogOnAttemptsHash] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [UserAvatarType] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [UserAccountLockReason] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_UserSettings_UserAccountLockReason]  DEFAULT ((0)),
        [UserPasswordLastChanged] [datetime2](7) NULL,
        [UserDataComUser] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [UserDataComPassword] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
        [UserShowIntroductionTile] [bit] NULL,
        [UserDashboardApplications] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UserDismissedSmartTips] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_CMS_UserSettings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [UserSettingsID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserActivatedByUserID_CMS_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserActivatedByUserID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[CMS_User] ([UserID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserActivatedByUserID_CMS_User]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserAvatarID_CMS_Avatar] FOREIGN KEY([UserAvatarID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[CMS_Avatar] ([AvatarID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserAvatarID_CMS_Avatar]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserBadgeID_CMS_Badge] FOREIGN KEY([UserBadgeID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[CMS_Badge] ([BadgeID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserBadgeID_CMS_Badge]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserSettingsUserGUID_CMS_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserSettingsUserGUID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[CMS_User] ([UserGUID])
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserSettingsUserGUID_CMS_User]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserSettingsUserID_CMS_User] FOREIGN KEY([UserSettingsUserID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[CMS_User] ([UserID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserSettingsUserID_CMS_User]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserTimeZoneID_CMS_TimeZone] FOREIGN KEY([UserTimeZoneID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[CMS_TimeZone] ([TimeZoneID])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CMS_UserSettings] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CMS_UserSettings_UserTimeZoneID_CMS_TimeZone]
    GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CMS_User](
    [UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_User_UserName]  DEFAULT (''),
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    [UserPassword] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_User_UserPassword]  DEFAULT (N''),
    [PreferredCultureCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [PreferredUICultureCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [UserEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_User_UserEnabled]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [UserIsExternal] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_User_UserIsExternal]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [UserPasswordFormat] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [UserCreated] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LastLogon] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [UserStartingAliasPath] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [UserGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserLastModified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UserLastLogonInfo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserIsHidden] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_User_UserIsHidden]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [UserVisibility] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [UserIsDomain] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_User_UserIsDomain]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [UserHasAllowedCultures] [bit] NULL,
    [UserTokenID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [UserMFRequired] [bit] NULL,
    [UserTokenIteration] [int] NULL,
    [CountryCode] [nvarchar](2) NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_CMS_User_CountryCode]  DEFAULT (N'US'),
    [UserPrivilegeLevel] [int] NULL,
    [UserSecurityStamp] [nvarchar](72) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CMS_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Show us the table definitions as well.

Comment: its already a primary key

Comment: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`???

Comment: No, `UserID` is the primary key. `UserGUID` isn't marked specially.

Comment: @M.Ali - it doesn't *have* to be a *primary key*. As the error message points out, *any* key would do e.g. a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint on that column would work.

Comment: `UserGUID` column is not a primary key that's why you can not refer it in other table as reference key. You can refer `UserID` column instead.

Comment: i generated this alter table script from other database and there its works fine , why this database having issues? both databases, table structure looks similar

Comment: i dont want to change the database table sctructre, its should be same in both databases

Comment: @SmartestVEGA - in the "other database", there's some form of key constraint on the `UserGUID` column - at a guess, it's a unique key constraint. You've failed to find/script/apply that constraint here and so that's why you can't apply the foreign key.

Comment: I did a beyond compare of create generated scripts of two tables in both database , both looks same .. then how this is possible?

Comment: Okay, so. Let's say that you've screwed up somehow and when you're scripting tables, you've told the system to not script unique keys. You generate scripts from both databases and compare them - of course the *scripts* compare the same - because if one database has a unique key constraint and the other doesn't, it's not going to show up in either of these faulty scripts.

Comment: In short, we can't help you because there's a fault in your copying process - and only you can identify the fault and fix it.

Comment: if one database has a unique key constraint and the other doesn't, it's not going to show up, i guess this statement is wrong, we can identity it as [UserGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [UserLastModified] [datetime2](7) NOT NUL from the script